# InvalidOperationException Collection was modified, but I did not modify it while iterating it?

Tags: .net, exception, collections, f#

I am currently programming a small server type in F# that basically stores active TCP connections with it. In its loop, it checks for new connections, and it also checks that current connections are still alive using the following code:

```
type TCPListenerServer(discoveryPort:int) =
    let server = new TcpListener (IPAddress.Loopback, discoveryPort)

    let activeConnections = new List<TcpClient>()
    let cancellationToken = new CancellationTokenSource()

    let connectionIsStillActive (client:TcpClient) =
        let ipProperties = IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties ()
        let allTcpConnections = ipProperties.GetActiveTcpConnections ()
        let relevantTcpConnections = Array.filter (fun (connectionInfo:TcpConnectionInformation) -> 
            (connectionInfo.LocalEndPoint = (client.Client.LocalEndPoint :?> IPEndPoint)) && (connectionInfo.RemoteEndPoint = (client.Client.RemoteEndPoint :?> IPEndPoint))) allTcpConnections

        try
            let stateOfConnection = (Array.get relevantTcpConnections 0).State
            match stateOfConnection with
            | TcpState.Established ->
                true
            | _ ->
                false
        with
        | :? System.IndexOutOfRangeException as ex ->
            false

    let rec loop (pendingConnection:Task<TcpClient>) = async {            
        let newPendingConnection, client =
            match pendingConnection.Status with
            | TaskStatus.Created | TaskStatus.WaitingForActivation | TaskStatus.WaitingToRun 
            | TaskStatus.WaitingForChildrenToComplete | TaskStatus.Running  ->
                (None, None)
            | TaskStatus.Faulted ->
                let result = pendingConnection.Exception
                raise (new System.NotImplementedException())
            | TaskStatus.Canceled ->
                raise (new System.NotImplementedException())
            | TaskStatus.RanToCompletion ->
                let connectionTask = server.AcceptTcpClientAsync ()
                (Some connectionTask, Some pendingConnection.Result)
            | _ -> 
                raise (new System.NotImplementedException())

        // Add the new client to the list
        Option.iter (fun c -> activeConnections.Add c) client

        // Switch the new pending connection if there is one
        let connectionAttempt = defaultArg newPendingConnection pendingConnection

        // Check that the connections are still alive
        let connectionsToRemove = Seq.filter (fun (connection:TcpClient) -> not (connectionIsStillActive connection)) activeConnections
        Seq.iter (fun connection -> activeConnections.Remove connection |> ignore) connectionsToRemove  // <-- Exception happens here


        Async.Sleep 1000 |> Async.RunSynchronously
        return! loop connectionAttempt
    }

    member x.Start () =
        if not cancellationToken.Token.CanBeCanceled
        then
            raise (new System.Exception("Cancellation token cannot be used to cancel server loop task."))

        try
            server.Start ()
            let connectionTask = server.AcceptTcpClientAsync ()
            Async.Start (loop connectionTask, cancellationToken.Token)
        with 
        | :? SocketException as ex ->
            server.Stop ()
            raise ex

    member x.Stop () =
        cancellationToken.Cancel ()
        Async.Sleep 2000 |> Async.RunSynchronously
        server.Stop ()
        activeConnections.Clear ()

    member x.ActiveConnections =
        activeConnections
```

In order to see if this works well, I have implemented this simple unit test:

```
[<TestMethod>]
[<TestCategory(Networking)>]
member x.``Start Server, Client Connects, then Disconnects`` () =
    let server = new TCPListenerServer(44000)
    server.Start ()

    let client = createClientAndConnect 44000

    Async.Sleep 5000 |> Async.RunSynchronously

    client.GetStream().Close()
    client.Close()

    Async.Sleep 5000 |> Async.RunSynchronously

    Assert.IsTrue(server.ActiveConnections.Count = 0, "There are still connections in the server's active connections list.")

    cleanupTest server (Some [client])
```

Unfortunately, when I run this test, I get the following exception once I have called `Close()` on the client:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.
>      at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException(ExceptionResource resource)
>      at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.Enumerator.MoveNextRare()
>      at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()
>      at Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.IEnumerator.next@224[T](FSharpFunc`2 f, IEnumerator`1 e, FSharpRef`1 started, Unit unitVar0)
>      at Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.IEnumerator.filter@219.System-Collections-IEnumerator-MoveNext()
>      at Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.SeqModule.Iterate[T](FSharpFunc`2 action, IEnumerable`1 source)
>      at TCPListenerServer.clo@35.Invoke(Unit unitVar) in E:\Documents\Source Control Projects\WiDroid\Core.Networking\TCPListenerServer.fs:line 61
>      at Microsoft.FSharp.Control.AsyncBuilderImpl.callA@851.Invoke(AsyncParams`1 args)

I understand that this exception happens when you modify a collection while you iterate on it. But I am not directly doing so in my code from what I can see. I am wondering why I am getting this exception?

Comment: I don't know F#, but my guess is the inactive socket cleanup code: `let connectionsToRemove = Seq.filter (fun (connection:TcpClient) -> not (connectionIsStillActive connection)) activeConnections Seq.iter (fun connection -> activeConnections.Remove connection |> ignore) connectionsToRemove`. I think iterating over `connectionsToRemove` actually iterates over `activeConnections`, which causes a problem when you then remove an item from `activeConnections` during iteration.

Comment: @wablab The exception happens at that place : ``Seq.iter (fun connection -> activeConnections.Remove connection |> ignore) connectionsToRemove`` indeed. I don't see how the two lists are connected though, and why iterating over one would iterate over the other?

Comment: You may want to consider using a binary search in order to trim down your issue into a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Often, in my experience, the mere act of doing that will enable you to troubleshoot your problem yourself.

Comment: I believe `connectionsToRemove` isn't a true list of objects; rather, it represents an expression with deferred execution that doesn't do anything until you iterate over it, at which point it begins iterating over the underlying `activeConnections` list. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/seq.filter%5B't%5D-function-%5Bfsharp%5D for more info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
let connectionsToRemove = Seq.filter (fun (connection:TcpClient) -> not (connectionIsStillActive connection)) activeConnections
Seq.iter (fun connection -> activeConnections.Remove connection |> ignore) connectionsToRemove
```

I think the problem lies there, `Seq.filter` returns a seq (alias for `IEnumerable<T>`).
What that represent isn't some sort of data container (like an array or a list) but rather a "computation which will give items at some point".

That means when you do the `Seq.iter` it has to "compute" `connectionsToRemove` effectively iterating over `activeConnections`. But in that same Seq.iter you ask to remove items from the iterated collections, hence the error.

If you're familiar with C# here is what the code *could* look line and then you clearly see the problem

```cs
foreach (TcpClient connection in activeConnections)
{
    if (!connectionIsStillActive connection)
    {
        activeConnections.Remove (connection);
    }
}
```

You could maybe replace that with a call to [`List<T>.RemoveAll`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
//doesn't seems to work directly (can't convert (TcpClient -> bool) to Predicate<TcpClient>)
//activeConnections.RemoveAll (not << connectionIsStillActive)

//this would work though
//activeConnections.RemoveAll (Predicate (not << connectionIsStillActive))

activeConnections.RemoveAll (fun connection -> not <| connectionIsStillActive connection)
|> ignore
```

Comment: Ha good to know! I had not seen that underlying logic. Your solution gives me the following error though: ``This expression was expected to have type System.Predicate<TcpClient> but here has type bool``. Can't seem to figure out why?

Comment: The following "long" way of writing it works though: ``activeConnections.RemoveAll (fun connection -> not (connectionIsStillActive connection)) |> ignore``

Comment: oh it seems an F# function isn't directly convertible to a .Net delegate (or at least not when "not defined explicitely") well something like that ^^ You can keep it the like you corrected, I'll edit the answer